# Using HTML5 file (Multiple) control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-upload

I am looking for a way to perfectly manage the `<input type="file" multiple="multiple">` tag of HTML 5 in my asp.net 3.5 project.
I have done it before with a single control on page, but what if we have multiple upload controls on the same page. Please see my code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//---------Need to check if my upload control has files: Please suggest a perfect way 
if (fupAttachment.PostedFile != null || fupAttachment.PostedFile.FileName != "" || fupAttachment.PostedFile.ContentLength>0)//here is a problem, as it does not checks for a blank file upload control
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            string strDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/") + "Mailer/" + hidCampID.Value;
            if (hfc.Count>0)
            {
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strDirectory))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectory);
                }
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(strDirectory))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        hfc[i].SaveAs(strDirectory + "/" + hfc[i].FileName.Replace(" ", "_"));
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}
```

My asp page is something like this:

```
//----this control is from which I want to multiple upload files
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" runat="server" id="fupAttachment" />

// Another upload control is there which takes input when page loads
<asp:FileUpload ID="fupMailingList" runat="server" />
```

So, exactly my problem is that when page loads "fupMailingList" has taken a file, and then when I want to use my multiple upload control "fupAttachment", I am unable to check if it has any files or not, as `hfc` checks for all upload controls and it gets file in one of them. So, please tell me a way to check only "fupAttachment" control and then do my work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over all the files in the request, you should check on a per input basis.

```
var uploadedFiles = Request.Files.GetMultiple("fupAttachment");
if(uploadedFiles.Count > 0)
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the HasFile property.

```
if(fupMailingList.HasFile){
//Do something
}
```